# Hibernate : map several columns into list

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a table which has these columns :

n_id, d_id, val_1, val_2, val_3, ..., val_50

How do I map this table ?

I would like to avoid this if possible :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "D_ID")
private String id;
@Column(name = "N_ID")
private String nId;
@Column(name = "VAL_1")
private double val1;
@Column(name = "VAL_2")
private double val2;
@Column(name = "VAL_3")
private double val3;
...
```